# Python: Printing unicode characters beyond FFFF

Tags: string, python-3.x, unicode

On Python 3 printing unicode characters can be printed like this:

```
print('\uFFFF')
```

But how can I print higher unicode characters like 001FFFFF? print('\u001FFFFF') will just print 001F as unicode character and then 4 times F. Trying to use print('\u001F\uFFFF') will result in 2 unicode characters instead of the wanted one. Is it possible to print somehow the unicode character 001FFFFF in Python 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an upper-case U.

```
print('\U001FFFFF')
```

Comment: Thanks, using an uppercase U is what I have looked for.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way in Python 3, using the built-in function **`chr(i)`**, which

> Return the string representing a character whose Unicode code point is
>   the integer i.

and

> The valid range for the argument is from 0 through 1,114,111 (0x10FFFF in base 16).

so there are no limitation for the hex digit value.

```
print(chr(97))
print(chr(0xFFFF))
print(chr(0x10080))
```